# QGraphicsView fitInView method: resizing problems

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a custom QGraphicsScene (my class is called MainScene) in my Qt Application. This scene contains some quantity of Rect items, that are placed as if in a grid

see picture №1

[image]

Also, I can change size of this grid of Rects dynamically

picture №2

[image]

Moreover, I want this grid to be fitted to size, so every time I press on Resize button ([picture №2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMkPw.png)), scene should be fitted to size like in the [picture №1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31gep.png). I implement it using following code:

```
void MainWindow::on_resizeButton_clicked()
{
    int h = ui->heightSpinBox->value(); //height of the grid
    int w = ui->widthSpinBox->value(); //width of the grid
    scene->resize(h, w); //adding required amount of rects

    ui->graphicsView->fitInView(scene->itemsBoundingRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    ui->graphicsView->centerOn(0, 0);
}
```

The problem is: when I choose heigth and width, where new height is bigger than current heigth and new width is bigger than current width (e.g. current grid is 20x20 and I resize it to 30x30) it works properly, but when I choose height and width that are smaller than current size (e.g. current grid is 30x30 and I resize it to 20x20) it doesn't work as I want

picture №3

[image]

Can you tell me, why is this happening? Are there any ways to fix it?

UPD:
This is how I create a grid:

```
void MainScene::resize(int rows, int cols)
{
    clearScene(rows, cols);
    populateScene(rows, cols);
}

void MainScene::clearScene(int rows, int cols)
{
    if(rows < roomHeight)
    {
        for(int i = rows; i < roomHeight; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < roomWidth; ++j)
            {
                removeItem(room[i][j]);
                delete room[i][j];
            }
        }
        room.resize(rows);
        roomHeight = rows;
    }

    if(cols < roomWidth)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < roomHeight; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = cols; j < roomWidth; ++j)
            {
                removeItem(room[i][j]);
                delete room[i][j];
            }
            room[i].resize(cols);
        }
        roomWidth = cols;
    }
}

void MainScene::populateScene(int rows, int cols)
{
    if(rows > roomHeight)
    {
        room.resize(rows);
        for(int i = roomHeight; i < rows; ++i)
        {
            room[i].resize(roomWidth);
            for(int j = 0; j < roomWidth; ++j)
            {
                    room[i][j] = new GraphicsCell();
                    room[i][j]->setPos(j * 30, i * 30);
                    addItem(room[i][j]);
            }
        }
        roomHeight = rows;
    }

    if(cols > roomWidth)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < roomHeight; ++i)
        {
            room[i].resize(cols);
            for(int j = roomWidth; j < cols; ++j)
            {
                room[i][j] = new GraphicsCell();
                room[i][j]->setPos(j * 30, i * 30);
                addItem(room[i][j]);
            }
        }
        roomWidth = cols;
    }
}
```

GraphicsCell is my custom class, that is derived from `QObject` and `QGraphicsItem`. `room` is a vector of GraphicsCell  objects.

Comment: shows how you created the grids

Comment: @eyllanesc See UPD

Comment: MainScene is the QGraphicsScene?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes. Sorry, I didn't match it in question. I will correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add items and if they are out of the `sceneRect` then the `sceneRect` is increased, and that's what happens when you add the `30x30` but it does not decrease when you pass the `20x20` so the scene is still big so you watch the `QScrollBar`s, so in this case the solution is to update the size of the scene to the `itemsBoundingRect()`.

```
void MainWindow::on_resizeButton_clicked()
{
    int h = ui->heightSpinBox->value(); //height of the grid
    int w = ui->widthSpinBox->value(); //width of the grid
    scene->resize(h, w); //adding required amount of rects

    ui->graphicsView->fitInView(scene->itemsBoundingRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    scene->setSceneRect(scene->itemsBoundingRect()); // <---
}
```